# rtk-query, don't invalidateTags when we get error

Tags: rtk-query

I don't want to refetch `REFETCH_TYPE_LIST` if I get error from this method

```
dosomething: builder.mutation<void, number>({
  query: (id) => ({
    url: `api`,
    method: 'PATCH',
  }),
  invalidatesTags: (result) => (result ? ['REFETCH_TYPE'] : []),
}),
```

What I can think about is to just make this condition, maybe there is another better solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always write an abstraction that is more readable for yourself, e.g.:

```js
function invalidateOn<T>({success: T[] = [], error: T[] = []}) {
  return (result: unknown) => result ? success : error
}


dosomething: builder.mutation<void, number>({
  query: (id) => ({
    url: `api`,
    method: 'PATCH',
  }),
  invalidatesTags: invalidateOn({ success: ['REFETCH_TYPE' as const] }),
}),
dosomethingElse: builder.mutation<void, number>({
  query: (id) => ({
    url: `api`,
    method: 'PATCH',
  }),
  invalidatesTags: invalidateOn({ success: ['REFETCH_TYPE' as const], error: ['SOMETHING_ELSE' as const] }),
}),
```

Comment: yea, I tried it but I get error from ts

The expected type comes from property 'invalidatesTags' which is declared here on type 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<number, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, DefinitionExtraOptions, {}>, void> & { ...; } & { ...; } & MutationExtraOptions<...>, "type"> | Omit<...>'

Comment: how to get type for ResultType?

Comment: I added a bit of TS up there maybe that helps you

Comment: you as the founder of RTK-Query, do you think this is a good solution in the long term run? My goal was not to trigger the re-fetching of ITEMS when I add a new ITEM and got an error, only refetch when I get a 200 status code from the server when I add a new item.
Maybe rtk doc. has other solutions I didn't find.